# How do I copy a view from one viewContainerRef collection to another in angular4

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am attempting to load multiple components dynamically and only have one of them visible at one time. Basically I am building an application that may have 100 or more components and I want to dynamically load a subset of those components at runtime into my application. I only want to view one of the components at a time but I want each loaded component to remain in the DOM so users can be editing on each tab and not lose changes when they change tabs. I am attempting to implement this using dynamic component loading and the ViewComponentRef abstract class. Since I want all loaded components to stay in the DOM until I delete them, I have created two container components and plan to hide one of them. The second container component will only contain the loaded component I want to be visible. I tried to do this using the get() method on the master collection and the insert() method on the selected collection. The code is running without error but it does not do what I expected. It does not copy the actual component content (i.e. html) from the master collection to the selected collection. How do I copy views from one collection to another and is there a different way to display only a subset of the dynamically loaded components.

Typescript

```
      import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ComponentFactoryResolver, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild,Type, ViewContainerRef  } from '@angular/core';

  import { AppletContainer } from '../appletContainer/appletContainer.component';
  import { AppletCollection } from '../appletCollection/appletCollection.component';
import { AdComponent } from '../ad.component';
import { TestComponent } from '../test.component';

  export class AdItem {
constructor(public component: Type<any>, public data: any) {}
}

  @Component({
selector: 'applet-frame',
templateUrl: '/NetworkDesigner2/views/app/appletFrame/appletFrame.component.html',
styleUrls: ['NetworkDesigner2/views/app/appletFrame/appletFrame.component.css'],
entryComponents:[TestComponent]
  })


export class AppletFrame implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {


items: AdItem[] = [];
@Input() inputControlStructure:any;
@Output() updateControlStructure = new EventEmitter<any>();


currentIndex: number = 0;
counter:number = 0;

@ViewChild(AppletContainer) adHost: AppletContainer;
@ViewChild(AppletCollection) master: AppletCollection;


constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  let newItem = new AdItem(TestComponent,{component:'sample manual component',description:'sample manaual component'})

  this.items.push(newItem);

}

ngAfterViewInit(){
}

ngOnDestroy(){}

loadComponent(){

  // Identify the current target component to load
  let adItem = this.items[this.currentIndex];
  // Create the component Factory object for the target component
  let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(adItem.component);
  // Declare a reference to the viewContainerRef object for the 'master' collection. This is the ng-template that will be hidden
  let viewContainerRef1 = this.adHost.viewContainerRef;
  // Declare a reference to the viewContainerRef object for the 'select' collection. This is the collection that will show the selected component
  let viewContainerRef2 = this.master.viewContainerRef;
  // Create the component
  viewContainerRef1.createComponent(componentFactory);
  // Clear the 'select' container so that I can copy over the targeted view only
  viewContainerRef2.clear();
  // Copy the targeted view into the 'select' container. For now this is hardcoded to copy the first element as an experiment
  viewContainerRef2.insert(viewContainerRef1.get(0),0);

  this.counter++;
}

loadSampleContentHandler(){
  this.loadComponent();
}

  }
```

basic html file

```
    <div class="l_appletFrame t_appletFrame" [ngClass]="{'l_extendedFrame':!inputControlStructure.summaryViewVisible}">
        <div class="l_appletBanner t_appletBanner" >
            <div class="l_revisionTypeContainer t_revisionTypeContainer">
                <div class="l_revisionLabel">Revision Type:</div>
                <div class="l_revisionTypeName">{{inputControlStructure.activeRevisionType}}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="l_buttonContainer">
                <div class="l_button t_button"><div class="l_textBox" (click)="loadSampleContentHandler()">Load</div></div>
                <div class="l_button t_button"><div class="l_textBox">Submit</div></div>
                <div class="l_button t_button"><div class="l_textBox">Close</div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="l_appletContainer" [ngClass]="{'l_extendedContainer':!inputControlStructure.summaryViewVisible}">

    <!--        <router-outlet name="primary"></router-outlet> 
            <router-outlet name="simple"></router-outlet> -->
    <!--        <sample-applet></sample-applet> -->

        <div class="l_collection"><ng-template applet-collection></ng-template></div>
        <div class="l_container"><ng-template applet-container></ng-template></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: For me it works well. Can you check this? https://plnkr.co/edit/Vjyo4h7ejGxJb5vdGgEh?p=preview

Comment: _Since I want all loaded components to stay in the DOM_ - why?

Comment: @Maximus Good morning. My clients want the same:)

Comment: @yurzui, good morning) the same is what? have nodes always in DOM? :)

Comment: @Maximus Yes, they want to have nodes always in DOM. They are afraid of losing data :)

Comment: @Maximus `RouterReuseStrategy` can be solution here

Comment: @yurzui, :D. Yeah I'll consider about putting my savings into DOM

Comment: @Maximus I don't want all components in the DOM all the time. I want to manage the lifecycle of components in the DOM. I may want two copies of a single component to be active at the same time so a user can look at one record in a UI screen and switch over to the other record in another view and make some edits. Basically a tabbed view where I can have more than one tab but only one active at a time. I will remove them from the DOM when the user closes the tab

Comment: @yurzui I looked at your plnkr and it seems to be working the same as mine. I am seeing all of the components show up in the Master collection but I do not see any of them showing up in the second collection. The goal here is to manage which component is visible to the user. I am investigating achieving the same goal using *ngIf in the component and passing in parameters to indicate which should be visible.

Comment: I got an acceptable solution to this problem working by implementing a service with Observables. I dynamically load an arbitrary number of components and pass in a unique ID as part of the component initialization. I also subscribed to the service in each component. I use the subject.next() method of the service to broadcast a changed value in my service and each component treats this as the active component ID. Inside the outermost DIV of the loaded component I include an *ngIf that compares the local ID and the active ID and only shows the component when they match.